# Warning CS8032 Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=3.3.0.0

Tags: c#

Getting the following warning. Projects loads and runs ok but I don't know how to get rid of this warning.
Visual studio 2019, WebForms.

> Warning   CS8032  An instance of analyzer Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.MetaAnalyzers.EnableConcurrentExecutionAnalyzer cannot be created from
> C:\Web Directory\VenueManagementSystem\VMSstartup\packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.3.3.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.dll
> : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
> The system cannot find the file specified.. VMSstartup  C:\Web Directory\VenueManagementSystem\VMSstartup\CSC   1   Active

Answer (score 5):

I think you experience the same issue [with this one on github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/1825)

Check your package.config file for an instance of `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` and try to upgrade to the latest version (this should do the trick).

In any case, I don't expect this to affect your application whatsoever. This is just related to static code analysis for your project and has nothing to do with your runtime execution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm already on the latest version,  did an uninstall/install but the warning is still there. Glad to hear that it won't cause  any runtime problems but would sure like to know how to get rid of it.

Comment: Check your dlls, is the missing one there? It might just be a different version and you can add a binding redirect